# Zeit asking me for "mysql2" dependency, but I have it installed

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js, mysql2, vercel

I'm trying to make a project work on zeit hosting. I'm using Node with Express and Sequelize with mysql2.
When I try to run the app in zeit, it give me the following errors:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
Duration: 425.50 ms  Billed Duration: 500 ms   Memory Size: 3008 MB  Max Memory Used: 96 MB 
RequestId: 2923134e-be9b-4223-96c7-dce58b5a0b19 Process exited before completing request

Error: Please install mysql2 package manually
-------------------------------------------------------
```

I have mysql2 installed on my project, and the app runs perfectly fine in localhost. What could be causing this?

I have tried to add node_modules on the github repo, and also tried to unninstall mysql2 and reinstall it as global, but both didn't work.

I just don't know if this problem is caused by some code error or some mistake related to the way I uploaded the files.
Here's the Github repo, you can check the project running on localhost normally.
https://github.com/vitorlimadev/employee_management_system

Answer (score 5):

This is a [known bug](https://github.com/vercel/ncc/issues/345) with `ncc` that has a workaround.

```js
let db = new Sequelize({
  dialect: 'mysql',
  dialectModule: require('mysql2')
});
```

See this comment: https://github.com/vercel/ncc/issues/345#issuecomment-487404520

Comment: Nice! Solved same problem with mariadb in Vercel.